# PhpStorm 2016.3.3 does not find test class with PHPUnit 6.0.*

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I want to run PHPUnit 6.0.* tests in PhpStorm. But it shows me the following error when I want to execute tests of a single class: "Test class is not specified or invalid".

[image: Run/Debug Configuration with error message]

I loaded PHPUnit with Composer. Here the `composer.json` content:

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Running the test in the command line is working. Output:

```
/usr/bin/php7.1 /path/to/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration MyTestTest /path/to/project/Tests/MyTestTest.php
PHPUnit 6.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 29 ms, Memory: 2.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Some additional information:

- PhpStorm settings:

  - PHP language level: 7.1
  - CLI interpreter: 7.1
  - PHPUnit uses Composer autoloader (link to autoload.php)
- PhpStorm Version: 2016.3.3

Tested it with 6.0.0 and 6.0.10. Assuming that all 6.0.* version are affected.

If I switch the version to 5.7.17 (last version before 6.0.0), it is working.
And as I mentioned, it is working when I select all tests in a directory, just not when I want to test a class or a method (error is the same).

Do I have a misconfiguration? Or is it PhpStorm bug?

I am attaching a minimal working example project for PhpStorm. [Minimal working example PhpStorm project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuGt81kAUCAIgSD3I_DAil3eyqi9)

It would be interesting if somebody could reproduce this issue with it or not.

Comment: Please try upcoming 2017.1 version for better PHPUnit v6 support -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/phpunit-6-and-phpstorm-2017-1/ ; post about RC https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/phpstorm-2017-1-release-candidate-1/ BTW -- 2017.1 **final** should be released either this or next week (could be even tomorrow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for PhpUnit 6 will be in PhpStorm 2017.1. You can get Release Candidate version of it.
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/index.html

Comment: Tried the RC and it is working flawlessly with it. Thank you and @LazyOne for the answer.